# How can I change the JAVA_HOME directory permanently on MAC?

Tags: macos, terminal, java-home

I have a problem with my JAVA_HOME directory. Every time I want to use `gradle` I need to set my JAVA_HOME directory again and again.

I know how to export it to the right directory but after I close my terminal, I have to do it all over again.

What I do is

`which java` --> `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home/"
```

to set the correct path. Everything is then set correctly, but when I close the terminal and get check the path again:

`echo $JAVA_HOME` -> `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Homeexport`

Can you guys tell me how to change the directory permanently? I googled so often and found solutions which didn't help me at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't so much a Gradle question, as an environment question. You would need to set `JAVA_HOME` in your shell's configuration. If you can tell me what shell you're using, I can point you in the right direction.

Since you're using ZSH, you can open `~/.zshenv` and paste this in:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home/"
```

Another solution would be to use something like [Jenv](https://www.jenv.be/) to manage your Java environment, with the `Gradle` plugin enabled.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am using zsh but can change also to bash

Comment: Hi riceplant. ZSH works just as well, I've updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks again! I tried to run `~/.zshenv` but it says  `no such file or directory:`

Comment: Feel free to create it, it's one of the files zsh sources by default if available. The alternative is to put the `export` into `~/.zshrc`, so you can also do that if you prefer to have less files

Comment: I put `export` in `~/.zshrc` and it worked! thanks a lot